# Generic interface requires type argument

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Is it possible to have an implementing class define the generic parameter for an interface?  Or, in other words, derive the generic parameter from the implementation?

In the example below, I want to be able to use the Repository interface regardless of the Entity type Id.

```
 1 class Entity<T>     // where id is either an int or Guid
 2 {
 3     public T Id { get; set; }
 4 }

 5 interface IRepository<T>
 6 {
 7     IEnumerable<Entity<T>> ListAll();
 8 }

 9 class GuidRepository : IRepository<Guid>     // this repo deals with Guid type entities
10 {
11     public Entity<Guid> ListAll()
12     {
13         // list all entities
14     }
15 }

16 class Program
17 {
18     private IRepository GetRepository(int someCriteria)
19     {
20         switch (someCriteria)
21         {
22             case 1:
23                 return new GuidRepository();
24             ...
25         }
26     }

27     static void Main(string[] args)
28     {
29         Program p = new Program();
30         IRepository repo = p.GetRepository(1);
31         var list = repo.ListAll();
32     }
33 }
```

As the code stands now, the compiler complains at line 18 stating:

```
Using the generic type requires 1 type arguments
```

In my real project, the method calling GetRepository is an MVC controller action and therefore unable to determine the type parameter at the line 16 level.

Comment: The line numbers are a bit redundant..

Comment: `IRepository` has a `T` parameter. What exactly do you expect the compiler should do?

Comment: Is `T` not defined in line 9?

Comment: What are you going to do with the `list` variable that you assign on line 31?

Comment: Does that matter?  I could print them to the screen or store them in another repository.

Comment: The `T` parameter is missing in line 18

Comment: Like this `private IRepository<T> GetRepository(int someCriteria)`?  If I do that, the compiler complains: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found'.

Comment: Like this:  `private IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>(int someCriteria)`

Comment: Do you have a Java background? Line 18 is correct in Java, but that's because Java generics work differently than C# generics.

Comment: :)  Yes, I did come from the land of Java.  Good catch-- I didn't realize this was a subtle difference between the two implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you treat a `GenericClass<T>` polymorphically with `GenericClass<Y>` where `T` and `Y` are different classes?

No. And that's kind of the point. You want type safety between `T` and the `Y`, which is what Generics offer.

I notice you say you can print both to console, which is true because both have `ToString()` methods. If you want a collection of objects that have this ability you want `GenericClass<object>`.

Mixing `IGenericInterface<N>` and `IGenericInterface<M>` under `IGenericInterface<O>` when `N : O` and `M : O` is called Covariance and [is a bit complex](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx), it's a interface thing that [is implemented when creating the interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd997386.aspx).